# Weird gaps in bibliography, list of figures, etc

Tags: spacing, biblatex

I have a very strange problem with my list of figures, list of tables and bibliography which I can't figure out. There are unnecessary gaps between the lines. Any idea what could be wrong here?

[image: bibliography]
[image]

The citation looks very regular to me.

```
@article{Falcone:uq,
Author = {Pete Falcone},
Date-Added = {2012-05-14 21:20:55 +0000},
Date-Modified = {2012-05-14 22:19:24 +0000},
Journal = {The Pantagraph},
Month = {September 28},
Pages = {B1},
Title = {Seattle; Historic Past Makes `Jewel of the Pacific Northwest\' a Precious Commodity},
Year = {1997}}

@book{Florida:2002fu,
Address = {Cambridge, MA},
Author = {Richard Florida},
Date-Added = {2012-05-14 23:18:17 +0000},
Date-Modified = {2012-05-14 23:19:31 +0000},
Publisher = {Basic Books},
Title = {The Rise of the Creative Class},
Year = {2002}}


% \documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,openright,numbers=noenddot]{scrreprt}
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,numbers=noenddot]{scrreprt}
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[british, english, american]{babel}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{sidecap}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{scrpage2} 
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage[format=plain,margin=15pt,parskip=5pt,font=small,indention=10pt]{caption}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\usepackage[titletoc, title]{appendix}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\renewcommand{\nomname}{List of Abbreviations} 
\makenomenclature
\DeclareCaptionType{map}[Map][List of Maps]
\usepackage{csquotes} 
\usepackage[
  style=mla,
  autocite=footnote
]{biblatex}
\bibliography{Bibliography}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\smartcite}[\iffootnote\mkbibparens\mkbibfootnote]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:mla}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
\makeindex
\clubpenalty = 10000 \widowpenalty = 10000 \displaywidowpenalty = 10000
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}
\counterwithout{table}{chapter}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,%
    citecolor=black,%
    filecolor=black,%
    linkcolor=black,%
    urlcolor=black
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I suspect that those high penalties can have a role in the business. But without an example it's difficult to say:  it may depend on many other reasons.

Comment: As a rule, it's usually a good idea to load the `hyperref` package *last*, i.e., after all other packages have been loaded. Well, there a couple of exceptions to this rule, notably for the `cleveref` package. However, all of the packages you're currently loading after `hyperref` could be loaded earlier without causing problems. Try loading `hyperref` last (just before `\hypersetup`, of course) and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: And by example, add some of the seemingly problematic `.bib` entries: it kind of looks like the two problematic entries are the same 'type' of BibTeX entry.  (You can if you want put it all in one file if you use `filecontents`.)

Comment: I added the bibtex example, but since it is nothing special, it won't help much. I tried putting hyperref at the end, but that didn't change anything. Also there are other entries of the same type which are perfect. Even if I use setspace for 1.5 or reduced line spacing, the gap remains there. This is really puzzling to me.

Comment: @Patrick May you add the contents of the `.bbl` file? The two entries corresponding to "Falcone" and "Florida" are needed, *exactly* as they appear in the `.bbl` file.

Comment: @egreg I added Florida and Falcone copy&paste from the bibtex. Worst is, the bibliography is not the only case, see the List of Figures. The gaps always remain at the same position, even if I change text. I'm not completely sure if they have the same size all the time though. I changed from scrreprt to report already and removed lots of packages but can't find the problem.

Comment: @Patrick The `.bbl` file is *not* the `.bib` file. The "problem" in the list of figures is probably due to the fact that the figures belong to different chapters.

Comment: Oh, sorry. But, as I found out, the problem was MLA. With chicago or biblatex-dw everything looks good.

Comment: @Patrick -- You should report this to the `mla` maintainer as a possible bug.  (This is not a standard `biblatex` style, right?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just had no problem with your sample bib entries in an updated version of Biblatex-MLA, which you can find here:

https://github.com/jmclawson/biblatex-mla/tree/dev

Since there have been many fixes between the released version and the updated version, I'm not sure what fixed things, and I'm not sure what caused troubles. Biblatex actually handles everything better than I expected, since your month field in Falcone is formatted oddly. Instead of putting the day there, use the date field to combine the year, month, and date. As an added bonus, setting the entrysubtype field will also format the entry to show up properly as a newspaper article:

```
@article{Falcone:xx,
    Author = {Pete Falcone},
    Date = {1997-09-28},
    Entrysubtype = {newspaper},
    Journal = {The Pantagraph},
    Pages = {B1},
    Title = {Seattle; Historic Past Makes `Jewel of the Pacific Northwest' a Precious Commodity}}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I'm closing in on the problem.

The penalties in the bibliography are caused by the MLA option. Once I remove style=mla from biblatex, the gaps in the bibliography are gone.

In the list of figures, the gap exists only between the last figure in a chapter and the first in a new one. This can be hacked:

```
\begingroup
\renewcommand*{\addvspace}[1]{}
\listoffigures
\endgroup
```